# Golangでgo get -u allを実行するとエラーになる

Tags: go

Golangのすべてのパッケージをupdateするために、`go get -u all`を実行すると、
`directory_name is not using a known version control system`と表示されてしまいます。
packageのupdateも実行されていないようです。
どうすればいいのでしょうか?

```
package cmd/internal/rsc.io/arm/armasm: directory "/usr/local/go/src/cmd/internal/rsc.io/arm/armasm" is not using a known version control system
package cmd/internal/rsc.io/x86/x86asm: directory "/usr/local/go/src/cmd/internal/rsc.io/x86/x86asm" is not using a known version control system
```

Comment: [cmd/go: package cmd/internal/rsc.io/x86/x86asm: ... is not using a known version control system Issue #12532](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12532)

Comment: `echo $GOPATH`で確認したところ
`/usr/local/go`は入っていませんでした。

Comment: 当該の issue はまだ fix されていない様なので、パッケージを個別にアップデートするか、もしくは一時的に `/usr/local/go/src/cmd/internal/rsc.io` を別の場所(`/usr/local/go/src` の外)に移動してから `go get -u all` を実行するか、でしょうかね。。。